# How to pass service data into initial state in Redux

Tags: javascript, angular, service, redux

I've got a service which works with my **Products** data in a shopping cart app.
What I want is to pass some data which is generated by the `getProducts()` method into *initial state* of my Redux part of the app.

My **service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Http, HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

  private products = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

  product = this.products.asObservable();
  dataUrl = "./assets/products.json";

  constructor( private _http: Http ) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get(this.dataUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  updateProducts(product){
    this.products.next(product);
  }

}
```

My **store**:

```
import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ADD_PRODUCT, REMOVE_PRODUCT, REMOVE_ALL_PRODUCTS } from './actions';
import { ProductsService } from './service/products.service';

export class IAppState {
    products: IProduct[];
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
    constructror(private _prods: ProductsService){ }
    products = this._prods.getProducts()
}


export function rootReducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PRODUCT:
            action.product.id = state.products.length + 1;
            action.product.isAdded = true;
            console.log(state.products)
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                products: state.products.concat(Object.assign({}, action.product))
            })

        case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
            action.product.isAdded = false;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                products: state.products.filter(p => p.id !== action.id)
            })

        case REMOVE_ALL_PRODUCTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                products:[]
            })
    }
    return state;
}
```

But compiler tells there's an error (Unexpected token) in

```
constructror(private _prods: ProductsService){ }
```

So how to pass the data from my *service* to the *initial state* correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import {provideStore, INITIAL_STATE} from "@ngrx/store";

bootstrap(App, [
    provideStore({counter}),
    provide(INITIAL_STATE, {
      deps: [MyCounterService],
      useFactory(counterService){
       return {counter: service.getCounterValue()};
      }])
     });
```